# Are the swords of the Nilfgaardians magical?

Tags: the-witcher

In the first episode of *The Witcher* (2019) we see the Nilfgaardians fighting against regular soldiers. Their weapons seem extremely effective: while we do see one hacking ineffectually at a shield for some time, we also see a sword slice straight through a steel helmet and right through the head below, which is basically impossible to do with a regular weapon, and another weapon apparently stab straight through a breastplate. By contrast, I don't recall any of the opposing forces cutting through the armor of the Nilfgaardians.

Are their arms supposed to be enchanted in some sense?

Comment: This same question could be asked about 99% of hollywood films, where swords can pierce through platemail, chainmail, gambeson, a human body, gambeson again, chainmail again and finally platemail again, to come back out on the other end. ;)

Comment: @Theik - Sure, but since the other side didn't seem to being doing it, I thought it might have been a "Nilfgaard thing."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the show strays from the book, then the answer is "No".

In the whole book series, contrary to the games, there is not a single magical sword. Nothing, nada - it is all about the quality of the craftsmanship. Even the famous "meteorite steel" witcher's swords are just well... a really good made swords - something that Geralt explains in details as one of the highly guarded witcher secrets. Jaskier/Dandelion at once stage notices a dwarven sword covered with runes. When asking what they mean, he hears:

> "Death to motherfuckers!"

The Nilfgaard Empire, among other things, is famous for their Viroledan swords, one of which Geralt very briefly had in the "Season of storms", which are apparently exceptionally well-crafted and famous for their sharpness.

So why the Nilfgaradian soldiers can cut through the armor? Well, it all depends on the armor itself, which can be poor quality in comparison to a full, steel plate. Other than that, it is obviously Hollywood "[absurdly sharp blade](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AbsurdlySharpBlade)" trope.

Comment: I suppose that could be what they are going for. But a steel sword isn't going to slice through a steel helmet, let alone the bone beneath once it is through. And sharpness isn't such an advantage for cutting through hard objects: what you need is weight or to concentrate the force at a point, like a spiked warhammer.

Comment: @Adamant The steel quality might simply be sub-par on the North and definitely will vary between armors. Also, out of universe, this is simply the special effect trying to show the brutality of the combat.